# SharePoint -force MasterPage check out

Tags: sharepoint

I know how to force check out for Lists Libraries.

But I am not finding a way to force check out for other files (including MasterPages).

I am using WSS 3.0.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I solved it.

The Master Page Gallery is really a document library -so we can set its versioning settings in this way.

1. Open Site Settings.
2. Open the Master Page Gallery.
3. Click on Settings/ Document Library Settings.
4. Open versioning settings and check "Require documents to be checked out...".

Thank you.